# How to enable Ambient Mode (Always On) in a FragmentActivity on an Android Wear App?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-fragmentactivity, alwayson

I have an android wear app that contains a FragmentActivity:

```
public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

With 2 Fragments:

```
public class MyFirstFragment extends Fragment
```

and

```
public class MySecondFragment extends Fragment
```

I want to enable the ambient mode (always on) in this fragment activity. However, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html#EnableAmbient), the ambient mode is only available if i extend `WearableActivity`.

**Is there a way to have both properties of the `FragmentActivity` & `WearableActivity` together in one?**

or

**Is there another way to enable the ambient mode in the `FragmentActivity`?**

Comment: Yes, extend FragmentActivity and implement AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider` instead of `WearableActivity`, then you can extend `FragmentActivity` instead.

It is the new preferred method and it still gives you all the goodies you got with WearableActivity but also lets you use `Activity` (or any sub classes... FragementActivity, etc.).

[Official docs call out the details (and example code)](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html).

Update: Use `AmbientModeSupport` now instead of `AmbientMode`. Google recently changed the name, so the old version is deprecated.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to only enable ambient mode on some Fragment and not all of them? I only want a few Fragments to support ambient mode and others should just close the app like normal.

Comment: You usually enable ambient support in the FragmentActivity in onCreate() with  AmbientModeSupport.attach(this).

Instead, you could create a custom interface the Activity must implement that triggers attach/detach (AmbientModeSupport) to enable/disable ambient.

In your Fragments, you could check that the parent Activity is of that custom interface (if it isn't, throw an error) and store a reference. Then you could trigger ambient mode against the casted interface that way.  That should work.

Comment: By the way, if it helps, you can set up a custom interface that Fragments must implement to tell Fragments to update screen for ambient (onEnterAmbientFragment, onExitAmbientFragment, etc.). Your activity would store a reference for that to trigger updates in each fragment when the Activity gets the callbacks (onEnterAmbient, onExitAmbient, etc.).  You could use that in conjunction with the above solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. This looks like the best way but I haven't been able to find a way to "detach" the `AmbientModeSupport`. So when I enable ambient mode support I don't know how to disable it again. Do you know how?

Comment: AmbientModeSupport has a detach() method (see link below). :) I would assume that works.  I figured the attach() method enables ambient mode so... detach() should disable it though you will have to try.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/ambient/AmbientModeSupport.html#onDetach()

Answer (score 2):

Answer to both questions is **no**, sorry.

Ambient mode is enabled by calling `WearableActivity.setUseAmbient()`, which obviously is not available if you're not extending `WearableActivity`. And since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance, you can't subclass both `WearableActivity` and `FragmentActivity` at the same time - it's one or the other.

Do you really need to be using Fragments on a watch activity? If you really want to support ambient mode, you probably need to look at moving your UI out of fragments.

Comment: when you have to implement a viewpager2, fragmentactivity makes more since. Google is conflicting itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Fragments on Android Wear and support Ambient mode, you need to use the `AmbientModeSupport` class.

Make your activity extend `FragmentActivity` and implement `AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider` and you're all set!

Details and examples are here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on#ambient-mode-class